# What voltage do I need for my solenoid magnet?

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, solenoid

I am looking to buy a suitable solenoid magnet for an experiment.  The experiment is quite primitive but I do need the right magnet although my knowledge of electromagnetism or electrical engineering is limited.

At the moment I have a magnet which holds a sphere of weight 2.1 g above the ground. I then observe what happens when the magnet is switched off and the sphere drops.  The magnet is a tubular solenoid magnet, 12 V DC, 10W and can be seen [here](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/tubular-solenoid/4317598/).

I now need a much larger sphere to be held above the ground against gravity by the magnet.  This sphere has weight 13.78 g, so roughly 6.6 times heavier.  Does this mean that the voltage of the new solenoid magnet would need to be scaled up accordingly by 6.6 to at least 80 V?  The only magnet I can find which would meet those requirements is 230 V AC, which is quite expensive.

For a diagram of the problem, see this paper, Figure 1.  https://thales.mit.edu/bush/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/aristoff-splash.pdf (Jeffrey M. Aristoff, John W. M. Bush : Water entry of small hydrophobic spheres)

Comment: The data for this solenoid says the force is 12N which is approximately 1.2 **kg**. Have you already tried this solenoid with the 13.78g sphere ?

Comment: What material is the sphere made of ? Can you provide a *diagram* showing where the sphere is positioned in relation to the solenoid when the sphere is being held above ground ? The magnetic force drops quickly as the distance increases.

Comment: I've added a paper which shows a diagram of a similar experiment.  So the solenoid magnet which I currently have given in the original post is wired up to a 0 - 30 V 2.5A DC power supply with adjustable current and voltage.  When the current and voltage are set to 30.5 and 1.3 respectively, one can feel a small amount of attractive force on the large sphere, but it is very small.  The diameter of the large sphere is 1.5 cm and the smaller sphere I normally use is 0.8 cm in diameter.  The spheres are made of stainless steel, basically stainless steel ball bearings.

Comment: Are you actually using that solenoid as intended (using the pull stroke to move something) or are you  "misusing" it as an electromagnet to directly hold your weight?  If you are using it as an electromagnet rather than an actuator, then you should probably be looking for a proper electromagnet instead of a bigger solenoid.

Comment: AJN is right, the magnetic force drops very fast as distance increases, so if the centre of mass is placed at 0.4 cm, and you then replace it with CM at 0.75 cm, the magnetic force drops by a factor of 3.7.

Comment: "Stainless steel."  Check it with a big magnet, not an electromagnet.  Many stainless steel alloys are (nearly) non-magnetic.  You might do better with a different kind of steel.

Comment: Yes I am basically using it to hold a weight directly.  For the experiment, I assume that it might not be a good idea to change the material of the sphere just yet.

Comment: Electromagnet strength goes up as the product of current and the number of turns.  This is known as "ampere turns."  To get a stronger electromagnet, you can use fewer turns, but supply a lot more current or you can use more turns at a lower current.

Comment: to add to what @JRE mentioned, in the actuator, the designers would have gone to great lengths to ensure that stray magnetic fields **do not** exit the solenoid body since the device is designed to pull an external object mechanically and *not* magnetically. So the magnetic fields **outside** this actuator are likely to be very weak.

Comment: You can break open this actuator (not recomended) to get the actual solenoid (and the magnetic fields) outside if you can't get a hold of another solenoid.

Comment: Ok.  You are misusing the solenoid. What you want is something like [this.](https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Electric-Lifting-Electromagnet-Solenoid/dp/B01N5OPUEC/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=electromagnet&qid=1594057262&sr=8-3)  I couldn't find anything like it from regular distributor, so I gave you an Amazon link.  You'll probably want to find one even smaller than that.

Comment: The "balls" in ball bearing come different grades and types of steel.  You might want to see if you can find some of a more magnetic material.  Carbon steel is usually much more magnetic than most stainless steel alloys.

Comment: Wait you ran 30V and/or 1.3A or 39 watts through a 12V 10W solenoid? Are you sure you didnt damage it? That's way beyond its normal voltage range and likely current and wattage ratings.

Comment: OK thanks for the explanations and help everyone, I've ordered a suitable fairly small lifting electromagnet and will then then figure out how to build this into the experimental set-up later.